# How would I Convert the list below from Celsius to Fahrenheit, using the map function with a lambda?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, lambda

I have been having a hard time trying to convert this list because it has a tuple inside and manipulating tuples isn't easy because essentially they're unchangeable. But apparently there are ways around it because I was able to adjust the numbers, however I am not able to bring back a string as well to make a new list. I receive this error when I try:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Swisha/Documents/Coding Temple/Python VI/tupe.py", line 4, in <module>
  newplaces = list(map(lambda c:  c[0] (9/5) * c[1]+ 32, places))
  File "/Users/Swisha/Documents/Coding Temple/Python VI/tupe.py", line 4, in <lambda>
  newplaces = list(map(lambda c:  c[0] (9/5) * c[1]+ 32, places))
  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My attempt with the error:

```
# F = (9/5)*C + 32
places = [('Nashua',32),("Boston",12),("Los Angelos",44),("Miami",29)]

newplaces = list(map(lambda c: c[0] (9/5) * c[1]+ 32, places))
print(newplaces)
```

My output without the strings:

```
[89.6, 53.6, 111.2, 84.2]
```

The required output:

```
[('Nashua', 89.6), ('Boston', 53.6), ('Los Angelos', 111.2), ('Miami', 84.2)]
```

Comment: I realized in my error that I was forgetting to put the coma after c[0] Thank you to everyone who helped me realize this small mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is a tuple (`c[0]` is the place name), so

```
# return a tuple that includes the place name
newplaces = list(map(lambda c:  (c[0], (9/5) * c[1]+ 32), places))
print(newplaces)
[('Nashua', 89.6), ('Boston', 53.6), ('Los Angelos', 111.2), ('Miami', 84.2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the first element of the tuple  also.

```
places = [('Nashua',32),("Boston",12),("Los Angelos",44), ("Miami",29)]

newplaces = list(map(lambda c: (c[0],  (9/5) * c[1]+ 32), places))
print(newplaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use list comprehension, rather than functional `map()` which is bad readability, if it is not learning purpose.

```py
# F = (9/5)*C + 32
places = [('Nashua',32),("Boston",12),("Los Angelos",44),("Miami",29)]

newplaces = [(place, (9/5) * c + 32) for place, c in places]

print(newplaces)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was required for this method, but I am always welcomed to try a better code in the future! I am still learning so thank you alot for the suggestion!